# Find the eigenvalues of $3\times 3$ matrix $A^3-3A^2+I$ where $A$ is a real matrix with diagonal elements $2, 3, -1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find the eigenvalues of $3\times 3$ matrix $A^3-3A^2+I$ where $A$ is a real matrix with diagonal elements $2, 3, -1$.

how to show this. Clearly diagonal elements does not treated as eigenvalues. A cannot be taken as a diagonal elements 2,3,-1 at the diagonal positions. Please help.

Edit

Yes I think that there is a problem in the question given. If I edit the question as

> Find the eigenvalues of $3\times 3$ matrix $A^3-3A^2+I$ where $A$ is a real matrix diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $2, 3, -1$.

what will be the solution

Comment: It seems very likely that there is a mistake in how the question was written.  Perhaps $A$ is supposed to have a certain structure (diagonal/triangular) that guarantees that the diagonal entries are eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only diagonal elements are given, construct two different matrices with given diagonal values, with different determinants. Then you would have different values of Eigen values for given equation. So it cannot be calculated.

Edit: for the edited question, the diagonal elements are Eigen values of A, using simple properties of Eigen values, Eigen values of the equation would be $-3,1,-3$

Comment: Edited my question. please answer

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is interpreted as an arbitrary $3\times 3$ matrix with diagonal elements $2, 3, -1$ then the eigenvalues can be anything.  For example, if $A$ is simply diagonal, then the eigenvalues are $(-3, 1, -3)$ but if you have 
$$
A =\pmatrix{2&1&0 \\2&3&0\\0&0&-1}$$
then the eigeinvalues are $(17,-3,-1)$

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly. Since $A$ is a diagonal matrix then:

$$A =\pmatrix{2&0&0 \\0&3&0\\0&0&-1}$$

Is one of the possible matrix. We make a permutation of the elements and get others matrix $A$. So,

$$A^3-3A^2+I= \pmatrix{2^3&0&0 \\0&3^3&0\\0&0&(-1)^3}-3\pmatrix{2^2&0&0 \\0&3^2&0\\0&0&(-1)^2}+\pmatrix{1&0&0 \\0&1&0\\0&0&1}$$

$$A^3-3A^2+I= \pmatrix{2^3-3.2^2+1&0&0 \\0&3^3-3.3^2+1&0\\0&0&(-1)^3-3(-1)^2+1}$$

$$A^3-3A^2+I= \pmatrix{-3&0&0 \\0&1&0\\0&0&-3}$$

So the eigenvalues are $-3,-3,1$.

Answer (score 0):

But you can write $A$ as an upper triangular (eventually with complex coefficients)  matrix and the eigenvalues of $A^3-3A^2+I$ are the image of the eigenvalues of $A$ by $x^3-3x^2+1$.

Comment: But one can form any A matrix, so the image is not unique.